# Discord.js assigning role to all users, works in test server but not on live server(command)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have slight issue I have discord bot in discord.js, we recently added 3 roles that are defaulted on each new member. But ofc this not apply to all the old ones and I dont really fancy assigning it to each individual user. So I made this following script below, This script works fully on my test discord server but throws errors on the live server. The error is"Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined". Anyone knows why that is the case?

```js
module.exports = {
    commands: ['updatetags', 'utall'],
    minArgs: 0,
    expectedArgs: "Incorrect Syntax",
    callback: (message) => {

        let cosmeticTag = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "━━━━━{Cosmetics}━━━━━");
        let otherTag = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "╶━━━━━{Other}━━━━━╴");
        let gamesTag = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "╶━━━━━{Games}━━━━━╴");
        const members = message.guild.members.cache.map((member) => member);
        for (let index = 0; index < message.guild.memberCount; index++) {

            members[index].roles.add(cosmeticTag)
            members[index].roles.add(otherTag)
            members[index].roles.add(gamesTag)
        }
        message.reply('Updated Role Dividers For All Members').then(message => {
            message.delete({
                timeout: 10000
            });
        }).catch();
    },
}
```

Comment: Will `message.guild.members.cache.forEach(member => { member.roles.add(cosmeticTag.id) })` work?

Comment: So this does not display any errors on live and test server. However it only adds roles to users on test server it does not add any on live server.
Could issue have something to do with amount of users in the discord server rather than the code itself?

Comment: I don't think so, probably it's something with your permissions on live server Ig?

Comment: I already have code that automatically assigns the roles to each new member + a command that allows you to assign it per specified person. So it shouldnt be permission issue?(both work on live version).

Comment: Did you tried console logging roles you are trying to add and check if it's not returning `undefined`?